# Calling async methods in a c# dll from delphi

Tags: c#, dll, delphi-xe

I'm writing a DLL in C# which goal is to communicate with a web platform using REST. It's going to be used in a Delphi XE program. The problem is, I don't really know how to go about exposing my DLL methods to be visible in Delphi. Basically all of them look something like:

```cs
public async Task<string> foo(string bar)
{
    string result = await client.GetSomethingAndReturnString(bar);

    return result;
}
```

Is it possible to use those methods from the DLL without registering it? Do I need some sort of a "bridge" in c++ between my library and the target program?

All parameters and return values are strings and I've read about marshalling etc. so I think making the conversion work won't be such a hassle, there are many threads about that.

I won't be writing the Delphi side, however I could have input on how my DLL would be implemented, if that is an important factor.

Comment: Yes you need a bridge. But that could be written in the same C# DLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick fix is to convert the `async` method to something synchronous:

```cs
public string Foo(string bar)
{
    string result = client.GetSomethingAndReturnString(bar).Result;
    return result;
}
```

Retrieving the `Result` property will wait until the function is done. Unless the task is cancelled or throws an exception. Slightly improved version:

```cs
try
{
    return new Client().GetSomethingAndReturnString(bar).Result;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    return e.Message;
}
```

(Though returning the exception message as data is probably not what you want.)

Or you can wait for the task to finish and inspect the result:

```cs
Task<string> task = new Client().GetSomethingAndReturnString(bar);
task.Wait();
return task.IsCompleted ? task.Result : "ERROR!";
```

Comment: If the GetSomethingAndReturnString method is called like that on the GUI thread, but internally relies on the message pump of the GUI thread to make progress, then this will deadlock. And this is true for both the .Result and .Wait() options.

Comment: That's a good and important point. As I understand it, the aim is to call a REST API, which is likely okay.

Comment: @PetterHesselberg no, is i not okay. Any inner unconfigured await will deadlock, this can happens with REST API call too.